Why is my Terraform configuration not loading credentials from file?
I have a CI/CD pipeline triggered by GitHub Actions which should run Terraform, via Terraform Cloud, and create a Supabase project. Everything works when I hardcode my Supabase access token into my Terraform configuration. I obviously don't want to do that.
My Supabase access token is stored as a GitHub repo secret. My plan was to write the secret into a file during the GitHub Action and have my Terraform configuration refer to the newly created file. However, when doing this Supabase throws the following error:
Unable to create project, got error: Post \"https://api.supabase.com/v1/projects\": net/http: invalid header field value for \"Authorization\""

This is the same error as I get when I deliberately hard code an incorrect access token.
The following is my intended workflow:
Directory layout
project
    .github
        workflows
            deploy-production.yml
    supabase
        main.tf

main.tf
terraform {
    required_version = "~> 1.9"

    required_providers {
        supabase = {
            source  = "supabase/supabase"
            version = "~> 1.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "supabase" {
    access_token = file("${path.module}/supabase-access-token")
}

resource "supabase_project" "production" {
    organization_id   = "***"
    name              = "***"
    database_password = "***"
    region            = "eu-west-2"
}

deploy-production.yml
name: Deploy Production

env:
    TF_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.HCP_TERRAFORM_TOKEN }}
    TF_CLOUD_ORGANIZATION: "***"
    TF_WORKSPACE: "***"
    CONFIG_DIRECTORY: "./supabase"

on:
    push:
        branches:
          - main

jobs:
    update-supabase-production:
        name: Update Supabase Production
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Checkout code
            uses: actions/checkout@v4
          - run: 'echo "$SUPABASE_TOKEN" > ./supabase/supabase-access-token'
            shell: bash
            env:
                SUPABASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_TOKEN }}
          - run: 'cat ./supabase/supabase-access-token'
          - name: Upload Terraform Configuration to HCP Terraform
            uses: hashicorp/tfc-workflows-github/actions/upload-configuration@v1.0.0
            id: upload-configuration
            with:
                workspace: ${{ env.TF_WORKSPACE }}
                directory: ${{ env.CONFIG_DIRECTORY }}
          - name: Create Terraform Plan
            uses: hashicorp/tfc-workflows-github/actions/create-run@v1.0.0
            id: create-plan
            with:
                workspace: ${{ env.TF_WORKSPACE }}
                configuration_version: ${{ steps.upload-configuration.outputs.configuration_version_id }}
          - name: Apply Terraform Plan
            uses: hashicorp/tfc-workflows-github/actions/apply-run@v1.0.0
            id: apply-plan
            if: fromJSON(steps.create-plan.outputs.payload).data.attributes.actions.IsConfirmable
            with:
                run: ${{ steps.create-plan.outputs.run_id }}


Validation steps
Terraform seems to find the file - if I change the path in main.tf then I get an explicit error.
The cat step shows *** in the GitHub Actions as you'd expect. I have verified that it reports sensible values if I write a non-secret to the file.
So...
I'm out of ideas. What am I missing? Guidance would be very much appreciated!


This is the same error as I get when I deliberately hard code an incorrect access token.
I'd wager you found the problem here - it seems like the token in your github actions secret is incorrect.


If Terraform itself were failing to read that file then you'd see a different error message from Terraform's file function. The error you included seems to be generated by the "supabase" provider rather than by Terraform itself, and so I expect that either the provider itself is buggy (sending an invalid Authorization header value) or your file contains an invalid value for access_token which the provider isn't properly validating, and so the remote API is rejecting it even though the provider accepted it.

The provider seems to literally just concatenate whatever you assign to access_token onto the end of the Authorization header value: https://github.com/supabase/terraform-provider-supabase/blob/20a3696cc0ce1a101ff621ec77913fa1501d44f0/internal/provider/provider.go#L78 ... so it seems like whatever content you have in that file is not valid syntax as far as the remote API is concerned.

My "psychic debugging" guess would be: your supabase-access-token file ends with a newline character and so you're effectively sending that newline character as part of the Authorization header and so the API is rejecting it as invalid. If that is what's happening then you could pass the result of the file function through chomp to trim the newlines from the end.
